# The custom extensions have not changed the version after updating the sap version

Tags: upgrade, sap-commerce-cloud

Hello I have changed the version of Hybris. When I enter the hac and give platform -> extensions. The custom extensions appear to me in their old version, before the update.
Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be changed in: `extensionName/resources/extensionName.build.number` you will find the `version` property there, you can change it manually to the new version number.

Hope this helps